# How to efficiently organize authentication & authorization using JWT in a microservice Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, microservices, backend

I am still a beginner in creating Spring applications, so I need to further grasp a deeper understanding of how microservice architecture works. So far I have read some conflicting opinions, and I want to adhere to best practice.

Following a tutorial on JWT HttpOnly cookie authorization in Spring boot, I have built a simple app that registers, logs in and logs out a user. It maps only post requests to /login /signup and /logout as a result. The Spring Security configuration in the app filters all incoming requests and populate the SecurityContext with authenticated object if the token is of a valid authenticated user.

Now the problem is that I want to build a separate Spring Boot app that handles other logic so that I can follow the microservice architecture paradigm. As the already built app's security config already handles the authorization in the HTTP request itself, I want to utilize this service to automatically authorize each request before it is forwarded to the next service.

I read about API Gateaways and the solution makes sense but seems too abstract to me to start building an implementation. Also I have a couple of questions: should the request first go to the intended service then to the auth service and then back to the intended one OR go to the auth service and then to the intended service? Which way is best practice? How to effectively connect the two services?

Any help will be much appreciated!

I have not yet tried a solution as I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

consider the following ;

for your order of request flow - it is generally recommended to first authenticate and authorize the request in the API Gateway before forwarding it to the intended microservice. it will ensures that only authenticated and authorized requests are processed by the microservices. and to effectively connect the two services, you can use service discovery mechanisms like Netflix Eureka or HashiCorp Consul. these tools allow services to register themselves and discover other services dynamically. You can also use load balancers to distribute the incoming requests across multiple instances of the microservices.
and by implementing an API Gateway, you can centralize the authentication and authorization logic and ensure consistent security across your microservices. It also provides a single entry point for clients to interact with your microservices, simplifying the overall architecture.so the follow up list will contain ;

1.Design the API Gateway: Determine the responsibilities of the API Gateway, such as authentication, authorization, rate limiting, and request routing. In your case, the API Gateway will handle authentication and authorization.

2.Create a new Spring Boot app: Start by creating a new Spring Boot app that will serve as your API Gateway. This app will be responsible for receiving all incoming requests and forwarding them to the appropriate microservice.

3.Configure the API Gateway: In the API Gateway app, configure the routes for each microservice. For example, you can define routes like /users that will be forwarded to the user service. You can also configure the authentication and authorization filters to validate the incoming requests using the existing security configuration from your already built app.

4.Implement request forwarding: Once the request is authenticated and authorized, forward it to the intended microservice. You can use Spring's RestTemplate or WebClient to make HTTP requests to the microservices.

5.Handle responses: Receive the response from the microservice and return it to the client. You can also handle any error scenarios and provide appropriate error messages.